# Can method_exchangeImplementations work between objective-c and swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c, objective-c-category

I'm trying to get a Cordova plugin to work with a Capacitor project.

Capacitor is in Swift and the plugin is in Obj-c.

The plugin runs this bit of code to *swizzle* itself in the app start flow.

```
+ (void)load {
    Method original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:));
    Method swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(application:swizzledDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}
```

`original` (application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) is in the Swift `AppDelegate` and `swizzled` (application:swizzledDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions) is in the plugin's obj-c code.

This doesn't work.

When the app starts, this bit of code runs, but the result of `class_getInstanceMethod` for `original` is always nil.

The swift delegate has

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
```

And the obj-c plugin has

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application swizzledDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   
    // ...

}
```

I've tried adding `@objc` and `dynamic` to the swift func but that didn't help.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Which class is `self`?

Comment: self is AppDelegate

Comment: The obj-c code is a category of AppDelegate

Comment: I don't see the sense of this exchange, this delegate method is called only once, so just call plug-in's method from app's one directly.

Comment: @Asperi Yes, that makes sense. Ideally I'd like to fix the plugin itself so it's compatible in my context, which means it would auto-hook itself as planned. My guess is the obj-c plugin isn't detecting the selector on the swift delegate but i'm not sure how to make it aware of it